# Is it possible to convert the whole page in grayscale except img?

Tags: css

I tried but it doesn't work:

```
body {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
img {
    -webkit-filter: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Of course it doesn’t. The image is part of the body content, and as such it is converted to grayscale. Saying “don’t convert me to grayscale _a second time_” is not going to make it colored again.

Comment: There is no standard for CSS filters, and it seems that the current implementation doesnt allow the grayscale filter to be removed from certain elements once applied. This may change in the future, but thats just how it is for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, apply greyscale to all element except images.

```css
body *:not(img) {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
h1 {
  color: red;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Phil is Awesome</h1>
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, corrupti culpa suscipit, saepe voluptas eius.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter works in this way: First it will render all the elements and it applies filters from parent.

Since you set `grayscale` to body. It will not re-apply to your `img`.

**Solution:**

Instead of applying to body, apply to all the divs required and leave the img.